# Stop all AudioSources in every scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I want to disable all Audio Sources in unity from my game's main menu and cause it to affect all scenes in the game by clicking on a button. And also I would like to enable it as well by clicking on another button (Mute Button and Un-mute Button). I have managed to accomplished this with AudioListener.pause function. But when I play the sound back with !AudioListener.pause, it acts like it resumed the sound back and plays all the sound that was paused with it creating a messy mixture of sounds. How can I go about this??

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to **mute everything** you can try to modify the `AuidoListener.volume` on your main camera object to just make it not output any sound that it picks up in your scene.

You don't even have to have a reference to the AudioListener component because `AudioListener.volume` is a **static property** of that class. To un-/mute you would just refer to the Class name itself and do something like this:

```
public void MuteAllSound()
{
    AudioListener.volume = 0;
}

public void UnMuteAllSound()
{
    AudioListener.volume = 1;
}
```

For further reference please check out the Unity documentation regarding the AudioListener component.

[AudioListener Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html)

**Alternatively** you can try to mute all AudioSources  by setting `AudioSource.volume = 0` and un-mute them by setting to `= 1`.

But as @derHugo pointed out this would not be a good idea since it is way **more effort/less efficient** and in this particular case it would be easier to just mute the AudioListener component completely.

If you wanted to mute just a **particular set of sounds** and not all of them this would be a viable alternative. Of course you would need to save the volume the source had before it was muted to re-apply it later and you would need a direct reference to all those AudioSources.
You could go about that something like this:

```
//Save the volume value and set it to 0 after
public Dictionary<AudioSource,float> MuteSourcesAndSaveVolumes(List<AudioSource> sourcesToMute)
{
    var sourcesAndVolumes = new Dictionary<AudioSource, float>();
    foreach (var source in sourcesToMute)
    {
        sourcesAndVolumes.Add(source, source.volume);
        source.volume = 0;
    }
    return sourcesAndVolumes;
}

//Re-apply your saved volumes
public void UnMuteAllSources(Dictionary<AudioSource,float> sourcesAndVolumes)
{
    foreach(var x in sourcesAndVolumes)
    {
        x.Key.volume = x.Value;
    }
}
```

You can, of course, always check out the Unity docs regarding the AudioSource component here:
[AudioSource Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)

I hope this helps!

//Edit: I switched the solutions to first present the better solution and added some code examples.

Comment: The second option using `AudioListener.volume`seems to be the best option for this case. To the first: It is less efficient and also there might be different volumes for each source so it would get more complicated. You should extend the second option into a full answer.

Comment: Yep I thought so as well. I'm going to do that tomorrow. Thanks @derHugo

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is to pause the audio system.

```
 public void ToggleSound()
 {
     toggle = !toggle;

     AudioListener.pause = toggle; 
 }
```

Unity Docs - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html